# Rename Wordpress Theme Folder

Tags: wordpress, themes, directory, rename

I'm trying to rename my theme folder (lets say it's twentyeleven) to something different. I have followed all the tutorials I could find which says I should first activate another theme, then change the folder name on the ftp, change the theme name in style.css and then of course activate my theme again.

I've also tried copying the theme and make the changes.

This does not work at all for me. The site looks really weird.

Am I missing something?

Comment: That depends on the theme, there are lots of bad coded "premium" themes where it's not simply a matter of renaming the folder, which works with good themes...

Comment: My theme is built upon twentytwelve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the links to the style sheets in header.php match the location of your new folder, if that is the case.
Also check links in style.css
For example:
<`link href="twentytwelve/style.css" ref="stylesheet" />` should look something like this.

Comment: I can't seem to find any link to a stylesheet in header.php.

Comment: Problem solved. I had spaces in my foldername. How stupid. Well, thanks anyway!